# Event Hub Converting JSON to JSON String

Tags: python, azure-eventhub

When we try to publish the json to Azure Event hub, EventData converting the JSON string. Instead of JSON string I need the JSON only at the consumer end.

```
response = {"status":"Active", "code":400}
event_batch = await producer.create_batch()
event_batch.add(EventData(json.dumps(response)))
```

At the consumer end I am getting the event as { body: '{"status":"Active", "code":400}', 'sequence_numbe':1} like this. how can we get only Json at consumer end like this

`{ body: {"status":"Active", "code":400}, 'sequence_numbe':1}`

Can anyone help?

Comment: My understanding is that, you are looking to get the event body as json - this is the event body : `{"status":"Active", "code":400}` in your example.

Comment: Yes @sathya_vijayakumar-MSFT. I want the event body as JSON not as a JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [body_as_json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-eventhub/azure.eventhub.common.eventdata?view=azure-python-previous#body-as-json-encoding--utf-8--) method to achieve your requirement.

**Sample Implementation :**

```
jsonbody = event.body_as_json(encoding='UTF-8')
```

This will directly return us the JSON Object

**Alternate Approach :**

Get it as string and then convert the same to json object.

```
 jsonbody = json.loads(event.body_as_str(encoding='UTF-8')))
```

Comment: @spring just wanted to check whether the above helped?